# Creating openCL buffers causes lag

Tags: c++, kernel, gpu, opencl

So I already have a kernel which creates an array of simplex noise values

```
int *landmap_flags = new int[68 * 68 * 68];
_clw.CLNoise(landmap_flags, clpos, LOD, chunkSize);
```

This works fine and allows me to calculate noise on the GPU, however, I've written another kernel to generate vertices based on the noise values and I require 3 new buffers for vertex information.

```
cl_float3* triangle_flags = new cl_float3[12 * 64 * 64 * 64];
cl_float3* normal_flags = new cl_float3[12 * 64 * 64 * 64];
cl_float3* index_flags = new cl_float3[6 * 64 * 64 * 64];
```

Without even running the new kernel, and only allowing a single of these new buffers to be created, the program takes an extra thirty seconds to start and drops to ten frames per second from the normal two hundred. I use new because I read that buffers this large on the stack will cause a stack overflow. Is there a better way to create large buffers for openCL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you allocate and delete these `cl_float3*` buffers on the CPU side repeatedly for each frame / kernel computation. Buffer allocation of course is slow.

Solution is to allocate the buffers *only once* in the beginning and reuse them over and over again, so instead of

```c
while(true) {
    cl_float3* triangle_flags = new cl_float3[12 * 64 * 64 * 64];
    // do PCIe data transfer and some kernel call / calculation
    delete[] triangle_flags;
}
```

do this:

```c
cl_float3* triangle_flags = new cl_float3[12 * 64 * 64 * 64];
while(true) {
    // do PCIe data transfer and some kernel call / calculation
}
delete[] triangle_flags;
```